# How to merge N sorted files in to one sorted file without storing in memory?

Tags: python

I have N files that are delineated by a new-line break. Each file has its rows/lines sorted in lexicographic order (the rows themselves don't have to be sorted). For example:

```
Include any error messages \n
Include details about your goal \n
Describe expected and actual results \n
```

How do I merge all multiple files so that the output file is sorted without loading all files in memory?

While this is not an algorithm problem *per se*, it does remind me of the leetcode problem of [Merging K Sorted Linked Lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/). In this case, a node would be one line in a file.

Comment: So what's wrong with [*any of the solutions suggested in the problem you link*](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/solution/)? Just implement one of those. You will just need space to store one line of each file in memory at the same time.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I can't hold all files in memory though. I'd have k lists (files in this case), with, say, N nodes (lines) each. All those have to be held in memory right?

Comment: Read my comment carefully. You only need to keep *one line of each file* in memory at any time. That is at most K lines in memory at any given time. This is more or less what the solution in the answer below is doing, using a priority queue (`heapq`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge):

If you have two files:

`file1.txt`:

```
aaa
aab
bbb
ooo
```

`file2.txt`:

```
ccc
ddd
zzz
```

Then:

```py
from heapq import merge

files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]

for m in merge(*map(open, files)):
    print(m.strip())
```

Prints:

```
aaa
aab
bbb
ccc
ddd
ooo
zzz
```

Comment: What does the asterisk do in this case? And aren't you opening all files, meaning storing all of them in memory? Or perhaps I am misunderstanding this.

Comment: @TheRealFakeNews No, `heapq.merge` is creating an iterator, so whats in memory is just two lines from the two files. `open(file)` is opening the file and you can iterate over it line by line.

Comment: @TheRealFakeNews From the documentation of `heapq.merge`: *Similar to `sorted(itertools.chain(*iterables))` but returns an iterable, **does not pull the data into memory all at once**, and assumes that each of the input streams is already sorted (smallest to largest).*